# pivot table for schedule by hour

Tags: pivot-table

I am have trouble figuring out how to Pivot a table. I need an out put that looks like this

```
    8     9     10    11    12    13    14
---------------------------------------------
1   test1 test1 test1 test2 text2 test2 test2 
2   test2 test2 test3 test3 text3 test3 test3
3   
4                     test3
```

i have data something like this :

```
name     hour  date
-------------------
test1    8     1
test1    9     1
test1    10    1
test2    11    1    
test2    12    1    
test2    13    1    
test2    14    1
test2    8     2    
test2    9     2
test3    10    2        
test3    11    2        
test3    12    2        
test3    13    2    
test3    14    2
test3    11    4
```

i also had tried with query like this

```
 select  [8],[9],[10], 
    [11],[12],[13],[14]
    from 
    (select name,hour,date
    from myschedule)as x 
    pivot
    ( 
    max(name) for hour in ([8],[9],[10], 
    [11],[12],[13],[14]) 
    )as pivottable
```

does anyone can solve this problem, i dont know how to query this stuff :(
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select *
from
(
  select NAME,HOUR,DATE
  from myschedule
  unpivot
  (
    NAME
    for HOUR in ([8],[9],[10], 
    [11],[12],[13],[14])
  ) unpiv
) src
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e808d/6)**